# MyBatisSystemException for Java17

Tags: mybatis

I try to upgrade our application to Java 17. but it seems have some problem:

org.mybatis.spring.MyBatisSystemException: nested exception is org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.PersistenceException:

#### Error querying database.  Cause: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make public int java.util.Collections$EmptyList.size() accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.util" to unnamed module @33b37288

#### Cause: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make public int java.util.Collections$EmptyList.size() accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.util" to unnamed module @33b37288

```
at org.mybatis.spring.MyBatisExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(MyBatisExceptionTranslator.java:96)
at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate$SqlSessionInterceptor.invoke(SqlSessionTemplate.java:441)
at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy91.selectList(Unknown Source)
at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate.selectList(SqlSessionTemplate.java:224)
at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod.executeForMany(MapperMethod.java:147)
at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod.execute(MapperMethod.java:80)
at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperProxy$PlainMethodInvoker.invoke(MapperProxy.java:145)
at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperProxy.invoke(MapperProxy.java:86)
at jdk.proxy3/jdk.proxy3.$Proxy94.listByCondition(Unknown Source)
at cn.zigaai.service.user.impl.RoleServiceImpl.page(RoleServiceImpl.java:105)
at cn.zigaai.service.user.impl.RoleServiceImpl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$4aba6e21.invoke(<generated>)
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:689)
at cn.zigaai.service.user.impl.RoleServiceImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$d915790f.page(<generated>)
at cn.zigaai.controller.user.RoleController.page(RoleController.java:64)
at cn.zigaai.controller.user.RoleController$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$3238041d.invoke(<generated>)
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:783)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:753)
at org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.MethodValidationInterceptor.invoke(MethodValidationInterceptor.java:123)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:753)
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:102)
at cn.zigaai.aspect.LogAspect.logAround(LogAspect.java:56)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:634)
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:624)
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:72)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:753)
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:753)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:698)
at cn.zigaai.controller.user.RoleController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$4af057a0.page(<generated>)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1067)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:655)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:111)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:111)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:327)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:115)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:81)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:122)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:116)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:126)
at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:81)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:109)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:149)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:219)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:213)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:219)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:213)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:111)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
at cn.zigaai.filter.ValidateCodeFilter.doFilterInternal(ValidateCodeFilter.java:45)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:103)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:89)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
at cn.zigaai.filter.JwtAuthenticationTokenFilter.doFilterInternal(JwtAuthenticationTokenFilter.java:46)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90)
at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:110)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:80)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:55)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:211)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:183)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:354)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:267)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:540)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:382)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:895)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1732)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

Caused by: org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.PersistenceException:

#### Error querying database.  Cause: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make public int java.util.Collections$EmptyList.size() accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.util" to unnamed module @33b37288

#### Cause: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make public int java.util.Collections$EmptyList.size() accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.util" to unnamed module @33b37288

```
at org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.wrapException(ExceptionFactory.java:30)
at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectList(DefaultSqlSession.java:153)
at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectList(DefaultSqlSession.java:145)
at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectList(DefaultSqlSession.java:140)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate$SqlSessionInterceptor.invoke(SqlSessionTemplate.java:427)
... 142 more
```

Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make public int java.util.Collections$EmptyList.size() accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.util" to unnamed module @33b37288
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:354)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:297)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.checkCanSetAccessible(Method.java:199)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.setAccessible(Method.java:193)
at org.apache.ibatis.ognl.AccessibleObjectHandlerPreJDK9.setAccessible(AccessibleObjectHandlerPreJDK9.java:58)
at org.apache.ibatis.ognl.OgnlRuntime.invokeMethod(OgnlRuntime.java:1211)
at org.apache.ibatis.ognl.OgnlRuntime.callAppropriateMethod(OgnlRuntime.java:1962)
at org.apache.ibatis.ognl.ObjectMethodAccessor.callMethod(ObjectMethodAccessor.java:68)
at org.apache.ibatis.ognl.OgnlRuntime.callMethod(OgnlRuntime.java:2038)
at org.apache.ibatis.ognl.ASTMethod.getValueBody(ASTMethod.java:97)
at org.apache.ibatis.ognl.SimpleNode.evaluateGetValueBody(SimpleNode.java:212)
at org.apache.ibatis.ognl.SimpleNode.getValue(SimpleNode.java:258)
at org.apache.ibatis.ognl.ASTChain.getValueBody(ASTChain.java:141)
at org.apache.ibatis.ognl.SimpleNode.evaluateGetValueBody(SimpleNode.java:212)
at org.apache.ibatis.ognl.SimpleNode.getValue(SimpleNode.java:258)
at org.apache.ibatis.ognl.ASTNotEq.getValueBody(ASTNotEq.java:50)
at org.apache.ibatis.ognl.SimpleNode.evaluateGetValueBody(SimpleNode.java:212)
at org.apache.ibatis.ognl.SimpleNode.getValue(SimpleNode.java:258)
at org.apache.ibatis.ognl.ASTAnd.getValueBody(ASTAnd.java:61)
at org.apache.ibatis.ognl.SimpleNode.evaluateGetValueBody(SimpleNode.java:212)
at org.apache.ibatis.ognl.SimpleNode.getValue(SimpleNode.java:258)
at org.apache.ibatis.ognl.Ognl.getValue(Ognl.java:586)
at org.apache.ibatis.ognl.Ognl.getValue(Ognl.java:550)
at org.apache.ibatis.scripting.xmltags.OgnlCache.getValue(OgnlCache.java:46)
at org.apache.ibatis.scripting.xmltags.ExpressionEvaluator.evaluateBoolean(ExpressionEvaluator.java:32)
at org.apache.ibatis.scripting.xmltags.IfSqlNode.apply(IfSqlNode.java:34)
at org.apache.ibatis.scripting.xmltags.MixedSqlNode.lambda$apply$0(MixedSqlNode.java:32)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
at org.apache.ibatis.scripting.xmltags.MixedSqlNode.apply(MixedSqlNode.java:32)
at org.apache.ibatis.scripting.xmltags.IfSqlNode.apply(IfSqlNode.java:35)
at org.apache.ibatis.scripting.xmltags.MixedSqlNode.lambda$apply$0(MixedSqlNode.java:32)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
at org.apache.ibatis.scripting.xmltags.MixedSqlNode.apply(MixedSqlNode.java:32)
at org.apache.ibatis.scripting.xmltags.TrimSqlNode.apply(TrimSqlNode.java:55)
at org.apache.ibatis.scripting.xmltags.MixedSqlNode.lambda$apply$0(MixedSqlNode.java:32)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
at org.apache.ibatis.scripting.xmltags.MixedSqlNode.apply(MixedSqlNode.java:32)
at org.apache.ibatis.scripting.xmltags.DynamicSqlSource.getBoundSql(DynamicSqlSource.java:39)
at org.apache.ibatis.mapping.MappedStatement.getBoundSql(MappedStatement.java:305)
at com.github.pagehelper.PageInterceptor.intercept(PageInterceptor.java:103)
at org.apache.ibatis.plugin.Plugin.invoke(Plugin.java:62)
at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy169.query(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectList(DefaultSqlSession.java:151)
... 149 more

this problem happen when code use java.util.Collections.emptyList() and mapperxml use if test collection.size() != 0

javacode like this:

Dto:

```
private Collection<Long> ids;
```

Mapper Interface:

```
List<Domain> listByCondition(@Param("condition") Dto condition);
```

Mapper XML:

```
SELECT * FROM `example` 
<where>
            <if test="condition != null">
                  <if test="condition.ids != null and condition.ids.size() != 0">
                    id IN
                    <foreach collection="condition.ids" close=")" item="item" open="(" separator=",">
                        #{item,jdbcType=BIGINT}
                    </foreach>
                </if>
         </if>
</where>
```

Comment: Try replacing `condition.ids.size()` with `condition.ids.size` and see if it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `size()` and `isEmpty()`, you can use the [pseudo-properties](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-ognl/language-guide.html#Pseudo-Properties_for_Collections) instead of the method.

```xml
<if test="condition.ids != null and condition.ids.size != 0">
```

There is an attempt to fix the underlying issue.
https://github.com/jkuhnert/ognl/issues/143

Answer (score 0):

Adding this in catalina opts or jvm runtime might also solve this " --add-opens java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED",
https://www.infoq.com/news/2021/06/internals-encapsulated-jdk17/